# Reduce memory usage of Android applications

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, bitmap, picasso

I am developing a simple Android application which displays a list of users by obtaining their details along with a profile picture from a server. The application consumes a huge amount of RAM(about 180MB). When I analyzed the memory consumption, most of the memory was consumed to display the bitmaps using Picasso. I use a recycler view to display the list of users. Below is the code fragment I use to set the profile images.

```
public static void setImageURL(Context ctx, String url, ImageView imageView) {
    Picasso.with(ctx).invalidate(url);
    Picasso.with(ctx).load(url).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(imageView);
}
```

Please give me some suggestions to minimize this memory consumption. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use pictures with smaller resolution

Comment: In fact, I think you should `load image with the size as you need`. As far as I know, `picasso` does not support this while `Glide` supports.

Comment: @Selvin I already use smaller pictures. Most of them are like 10KB and I don't even have 20 users to display.

Comment: glide is also changing bytes per pixel (it using RGB_565(2 bytes per pixel) when normal is ARGB_8888(4 bpp))

Comment: *Most of them are like 10KB* again size of the file doesn't matter

Comment: @Selvin If server provides `1000 x 500` image, `picasso` load `1000 x 500` while `Glide` support loading `500 x 250`.

Comment: try recycling the bitmap with bitmap.recycle() or set the bitmap as null after use so that they can be collected by the garbage collector

Comment: @LiJianixn ... Picasso is supporting resizing too ... take a look at resize ... centerCrop ... centerInside ... fit and so  on methods

Comment: @Selvin Sorry for forgetting that. But `Glide` automatically resizes for you.

Comment: @selvin I resized the images and there's a small reduction in memory consumption but not enough. Anyway thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: @LiJianixn thanks I will try Glide next time. :)

Comment: @free_style I don't keep any reference of the bitmaps in my code. Is there any way to tell Picasso to release any memory its threads are holding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with loading images using Picasso without fitting them. Simply adding fit() after load() resolved the issue.

```
   Picasso.with(ctx).load(url).fit().networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(imageView);
```